# Need advices on design of classes for IAP in Parse

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, parse-platform

My application is an ebook store app which sell books and also provide free books. I need to show them on a UIViewController at the same time. I need some advices on how I should design the data in Parse since I'm still very new to parse.

At first I created a class called Book, it looks like this one:

```
objectId  productId  name  downloaded  free  file
```

I'd like to use this class for both free and non-free book. But I can't do this because it seems parse need to create a Product class for IAP.

How am I supposed to link my class to Product class without any duplication of data? Is the one-to-one relation the best choice?

If I'm using one-to-one relation to attach the Product to my Book class, the productIdentifier is the only column I need in Product class. And it will be the duplication of my productId column in Book class.

Are there any better suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two properties in your class that aren't in the Parse.com `Product` class - "free" and "downloaded".

You don't need the "free" property because you can set the price tier for the corresponding in-app purchase product in iTunesConnect to free and retrieve the pricing information from the iTunes store to display in your app.

If you do want to keep a track of the "downloaded" status for each piece of content then you will need another object, which will have your "downloaded" property, the "productID" property and something that ties the data back to a particular user or purchase.  In this case you do need to duplicate the productID, but this is because it is the key that builds the relationship

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I use parse Product class for free product? If I don't have a "free" column, how can I know the product is free or not? (There is no way to create a "free" IAP item in iTunes connect).

Comment: When you create the in-app purchase item in iTunesconnect set its price tier to "free" - you can then retrieve the price from the product list in iTunes

Comment: Thanks. That's great. When did Apple start to allow this?

Comment: I don't know.  I thought there was always a free tier

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the price from parse sdk?

Comment: No, you will need to retrieve the product details from the App Store using the in-app purchase APIs